# (fixing a code for) racket-- deleting a node from a tree

Tags: racket, binary-search-tree

So I'm currently stuck in the intermediate level of racket, and have looked at various codes, but most of them I can't figure out
I'm trying to delete a node from a binary search tree

So, I've so far come up with this, which includes an empty node and the first and final node in the wrong order

```
    (define-struct node (key value left right))

    (define (delete bst k)
  (local [(define empty-l (empty? (node-left bst)))
          (define empty-r (empty? (node-right bst)))
          (define full-l (not empty-l))
          (define full-r (not empty-r))]

    (local [(define (replace bst) 
              ;;takes node and takes it away, finding the next part that should take over its spot
              (cond
                [(empty? bst) empty]
                [(and empty-l empty-r) empty]
                [(and empty-l full-r) (node-right bst)]
                [(and full-l empty-r) (node-left bst)]
                [(and full-l full-r) (make-node                                  
                                      (if (**empty? (node-right bst)) "MAKE_THIS_KEY_GO_AWAY"**  (node-key (node-right bst)))
                                      (if (**empty? (node-right bst)) "MAKE_THIS_VALUE_GO_AWAY"** (node-value (node-right bst)))
                                      ;(node-value (node-right bst))
                                      (node-left bst)
                                      (replace (node-right bst)))]))]

      ;(local ((define (find k bst)
      ;;if finds k, puts it through replace to replace it
      (cond
        [(empty? bst) empty]
        [(= k (node-key bst)) (replace bst)]
        [(< k (node-key bst)) (make-node (node-key bst)
                                         (node-value bst)
                                         (delete k (node-left bst))
                                         (node-right bst))]
        [else (make-node (node-key bst)
                         (node-value bst)
                         (node-left bst)
                         (delete k (node-right bst)))]))))

;; Example binary search tree for check-expect
(define t (make-node 5 "" (make-node 3 "" (make-node 2 "" (make-node 1 "" empty empty)
                                                     empty)
                                     (make-node 4 "" empty empty))
                     (make-node 7 "" (make-node 6 "" empty empty) empty)))



(check-expect (delete t 5)
              (**make-node 6 ""** (make-node 3 "" (make-node 2 "" (make-node 1 "" empty empty)
                                                         empty)
                                         (make-node 4 "" empty empty))
                         (**make-node 7 ""** empty empty)))


;;What I actually get
(**make-node
 7
 ""**
 (make-node
  3
  ""
  (make-node
   2
   ""
   (make-node 1 "" empty empty)
   empty)
  (make-node 4 "" empty empty))
 (**make-node
  "MAKE_THIS_KEY_GO_AWAY"
  "MAKE_THIS_VALUE_GO_AWAY"**
  (**make-node 6 ""** empty empty)
  empty))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(full-l full-r)` case is all messed up. To handle that case, you need to pick either what Wikipedia calls the "in-order predecessor" or the "in-order successor" of the instance of `bst` being handled by `replace`, then delete that key from `replace`'s `bst` and make it be the replacement. These functions can be used to find the in-order predecessor/successor:

```
(define (in-order-predecessor tree)
  (right-bottom (node-left tree)))

(define (in-order-successor tree)
  (left-bottom (node-right tree)))

(define (left-bottom tree)
  (if (empty? (node-left tree))
      tree
      (left-bottom (node-left tree))))

(define (right-bottom tree)
  (if (empty? (node-right tree))
      tree
      (right-bottom (node-right tree))))
```

So you'd do something like this:

```
[(and full-l full-r)
 (local [(define successor (in-order-successor bst))
         (define old-right (node-right bst))
         (define new-right (delete old-right (node-key successor)))]
     (make-node (node-key successor) (node-value successor)
                (node-left bst) new-right))]
```

Since this version of `replace` would no longer be recursive, it doesn't need to receive `bst` as an argument.

Also, you're getting the argument order of `delete` mixed up. You defined it as `(delete node k)` but in two places you call it as `(delete k node)`.